# Angular 2+ template driven forms - Detect re-editing of a field

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

How do I detect that a field has been re-edited to correct a validation error? The field has been invalid but the user has started to correct it. Doesn't seem possible with only the `touched` and `dirty` properties?

The scenario is that I want to display an error label on blur but then display another label when the user revisits the field.

Comment: There is no static boolean flag for this. You have to subscribe to the `statusChanges` observable of the control and track state transitions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a directive that you need to add to the field.
This is not a actuall answer but like how you should proceed to the problem

like so [example of onblur in reactive forms]

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[validate-onblur]',
  host: {
    '(focus)': 'onFocus($event)',
    '(blur)': 'onBlur($event)'
  }
})
export class ValidateOnBlurDirective {
    constructor(public formControl: NgControl) {
    }

    onFocus($event) {
      this.formControl.control.markAsUntouched({onlySelf: true});
    }

    onBlur($event) {
      this.formControl.control.markAsTouched({onlySelf: false});
    }
}
```

When the user visits the Url first time the properties will be pristine and on blur you need to mark it as untouched and show error for pristine
then next time when he comes it becomes untouched you now show the error for untouched.

It is not a actual solution but like a psuedo code . 
I have made use of directives to achieve onBlur in Reactive forms 
[LINK](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive)

Comment: This breaks all other logic that depends on the touched flags to work as expected.

Comment: yes it will but for a particular form it will work , if you check tha link @ThinkingMedia you will c i have used it there